# I deleted an HTML file. What is the proper way to tell Search Engines its gone? 204 error code?

Tags: .htaccess

Is there something I should put in my htaccess to tell google the file is gone?

Comment: This really belongs on [webmasters.SE], I think. But don't re-ask it there; it should get migrated shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

410 Gone "indicates that the resource requested is no longer available and will not be available again".

With that said, there is no SEO advantage to telling the search engines to remove a listing of your site. Make a nice 404 page that directs the user to other related content on your site.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. Your server will return a 404 error code by default, which is the accepted and proper way to tell search engines and other visitors that the page does not exist. (A 204 code would indicate that the file still exists, but that its metadata has changed)

You can, optionally, use the 410 status code, which is like a "stronger" version of 404: not only does it indicate that the file is not present (as 404 does), but it also indicates that the condition is permanent, i.e. that the page will never be restored at that URL, and that the reason the page is gone is *not* that it has moved elsewhere. In practice, a lot of clients treat several of the 4xx status codes more or less equivalently, so you're not likely to get much of a practical benefit by using it instead of 404.

Here is a [full listing of HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: " it also indicates that the condition is permanent" - ya the file is totally deleted and will never be back. I had a bad google experience once where the deletion of 20 files prompted a 90% decrease in traffic - i am theorizing that "lettingn them know" will help - but just a theory. I think maybe 410 is the way to go... - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, people frequently use [`301` responses](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) to indicate that the content has moved elsewhere. It helps prevent loss of page rank when, for example, migrating across subdomains.

Comment: "people frequently use 301 responses to indicate that the content has moved elsewhere" - thanks. but ya the content was destroyed

Comment: Regardless, you're leaving search juice on the table if you fail to redirect.